# ERROR: make sure that the index is less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net

When I select/click the first 2 rows individually, I am fine. I get an error if I select/click any row after that. The error message is:
" Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"
I added a RowIndexCount to count how many rows the application is reading, and it returns 84. What is possible wrong with it?
VB.NET

```
    Dim rowDGVDataPhys As Integer = DGVDataPhys.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    txtRowIndex.text = rowDGVDataPhys
    DGVDataPhys.Rows(rowDGVDataPhys).Selected = True
    DGVData.Enabled = True
    DGVDataPhys.Enabled = True
    Dim CountRowIndexes As Integer = 0
    CountRowIndexes = DGVDataPhys.RowCount

'To capture how many total rows in the GRID.        
MsgBox(CountRowIndexes) 'I found 84 rows 
        vDeptID = DGVDataPhys.Rows(DGVDataPhys.SelectedCells(rowDGVDataPhys).RowIndex.ToString()).Cells("DeptKey").Value
        vDeptName = DGVDataPhys.Rows(DGVDataPhys.SelectedCells(rowDGVDataPhys).RowIndex.ToString()).Cells("DeptName").Value
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indexing row using the SelectedCells collection, not the Current cells Row index...

Do this instead

```
    vDeptID = DGVDataPhys.Rows(rowDGVDataPhys).Cells("DeptKey").Value
    vDeptName = DGVDataPhys.Rows(rowDGVDataPhys).Cells("DeptName").Value
```